# Set array of TabBar items dynamically with scroll view

Tags: iphone

How can I add a TabBar on top of the iPhone?  Also I need to set an array of TabBar items dynamically with scroll view.

For more details refer to [this url](http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/080/Purple/v4/9b/b3/79/9bb3791e-1780-020c-3bde-e017309b4b76/mzl.myolzqar.320x480-75.jpg)

I need to create tabs like Top News, City, India, World, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`UITabBar` generally is placed at the bottom of the screen and there usually only one per app.  It may be possible to sidestep this, though Apple probably won't like it.

You do not directly manipulate a `UITabBar`.  Instead, you add navigationControllers to the `UITabBarController`.  Tabs can then be manipulated by setting the tabBarItem property on the NavigationController.

All that said having reviewed the screenshot, I am almost certain that a UITabBar is the wrong choice for this.  You'd be better off rolling your own control or perhaps using `UISegmentedControl`.